# Does cached js file slow down the page rendering

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using a kendo library for my project. I have to load 250 rows in a kendo grid but rendering is very slow & after loading the page becomes unresponsive. When i checked in the firebug i found kendo.all.min.js file size is(2.37 MB) which is cached by browser. does it impact on rendering

Comment: are you seeing this in several browsers?

Comment: yup but IE is much slower than other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `kendo.all.min.js` being cached or not, it's just to do with your data set. Think about it, kendo is having to manipulate the DOM for 250 rows and it will get worse as the data set grows. You can test this yourself by reducing the number of rows to, for example, 20 and you will see that the browser renders it quicker.

Generally, if you're using Kendo with `ASP.NET`, your Kendo helper inside the view is actually rendering a script on to the page. When that page loads fully, the `kendo.all.min.js` file will then convert this into a Grid. Of course, ignore this if you're doing this all server side.

Finally, although this has no bearing on the question, don't use `kendo.all.min.js` unless you're using each component inside this file. You'll just need `kendo.grid.js` and it's dependencies. In web terms 2.37mb is huge for a .js file. Each person who visits your website has to download a file that size and it will impact on their load times hugely.

Answer (score 2):

To further analyse where the problem is coming from, are you seeing this in all browsers?

Have you seen Glimpse http://getglimpse.com/ it is great for debugging performance issues on ASP.net both server and client side, this should give you an indication of where the delay is coming from.

I can't comment on how efficient Kendo is, I have not used it, but 2.37MB minified is extremely large for a javascript file (for example Jquery is 90kb). How the file is parsed and how this affects rendering could be different between browsers - but 250 rows is nothing really to render in a javascript style table - I have used http://datatables.net/ to render 1000's of rows client side with no notable performance loss.